# Using a different linker when running gcc

Tags: gcc, ld

`gcc` uses the linker `ld` located under `/usr/local/bin` by default when linking. How can I change it and point gcc to a different inker to use?

I don't want to rebuild gcc from source.

I have tried the `-B` option, also tried adding the path of my linker to the start of PATH env variable but they did not work.

Comment: The program `gcc` is just a front-end program that ruins the actual compiler and linker behind the scenes. You can ask `gcc` to stop at any step: Preprocessing, compilation (generating assembly code) or after generating an object file. If you stop after generating an object file (using the `-c` option), you can use any suitable linker to link the object files into the final executable program.

Comment: With that said, I'm very curious about *why* you want to do this? What linker do you want to use instead? For what purpose? What is the *real* problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Im on solaris, need to use gold linker instead of solaris linker, because solaris liker doesn't understand some of the options. I also use a wrapper that calls gcc so can't just stop mid compilation.

Comment: `gcc` have standard options to use the `gold` linker instead. Please [read the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) (`-fuse-ld=gold`)

Comment: tried, didn't work

Comment: Then please edit your question to tell us the problem, what you have tried and how it didn't work. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).